# Error while creating cocoa pod for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I was following all the instruction given on cocoapods.org website for creating pod library.
Every thing was going go, like validation and everything.
When I issue command

```
pod trunk push myLibName
```

I get following error. If anyone can help me out to find out what is going wrong, It would be very much appreciated.

````
    ### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `last' for #<Netrc::Entry:0x007fac860cb248>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-0.1.4/lib/pod/command/trunk.rb:390:in `token'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-0.1.4/lib/pod/command/trunk.rb:259:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.6.1/lib/claide/command.rb:280:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
````

Answer (score 0):

According to this article you need to update your version of Cocoapods.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2674

```
    $ gem install cocoapods
```

Larry